# Python Debugging : Find where an exception is raised, go into debug mode?

Tags: python, debugging, exception, pdb

Is there a command in the Python debugger (pdb) that says something like "run until the next exception is raised?"

Seems an obvious requirement but can't seem to find it.

Update : To be clear, my problem is an exception which is being caught and turned into an inadequate message in a log file. And I can't find where the exception is raised.

I figured that if I could go into trace mode and say "run until an exception is thrown" that would be the most straightforward way of finding it. I don't think post-mortem will work here.

Comment: This is called Post Mortem debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your script as follows:

```
python -m pdb myscript.py
```

Press `c` and `Enter`.
When an uncaught exception is raised you program will stop running and fall back to the pdb debug prompt.

Comment: Actually my problem is that the exception IS caught. (And effectively suppressed with an inadequate message in the logs). I just don't know where it's generated. That's what I was trying to find. I figured that if I could start in pdb trace mode and say "run until you find an exception" that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Can you search the code in the failing script for the text of the message that is logged (I realize that this may be difficult if the string is generated in a complex way). If you can find the point where the message is generated/logged then you can set an appropriate break point to troubleshoot the problem.

Unfortunately, AFAIK Python `pdb` debugging does not offer the capability that is present in some other languages to say, for example, `break when Exception is raised`.

Comment: Unfortunately the message just is the original Exception message. (A missing attribute). It's coming from the system. But it isn't attached to an Exception object which is why I can then do a post-mortem on it. (doh!)

Ah well, if pdb doesn't do it, I'll have to look for an alternative. Cheers.